# How to stop enqueueing same script more than once inside wordpress shortcode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

First of all I'm requesting all of you to please read the question fully before hitting negative arrow, I'm really in a very wired problem here and didn't find any similar answers on the web.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm creating a wordpress plugin after installing which you just need to add a shortcode and pass some parameters with the shortcode and then it will show up a slider within your article based on your parameter data.

Now as it is a slider, it is mostly based on jQuery to do the fancy stuffs. Now to pass the shortcode parameters to the jquery I'm taking help of `wp_localize_script()` so that I can access the shortcode parameters inside my jquery script.

**The Problem:**

As I'm passing the shortcode attribute values to the localization script, I must need to call the `wp_register_script()`, `wp_localize_script()`, `wp_enqueue_script()` all inside the `add_shortcode()` block.

Because if I create another function outside of `add_shortcode()` to just enqueue my scripts wp `wp_enqueue_scripts` action, then it will get fired first even before executing the shortcode. So the `wp_localize_script()` can never pass the shortcode attributes to the jquery script.

```
add_shortcode('some_shortcode', function( $atts ) {
    //extracting the shortcode attributes
    $shortcode_data = shortcode_atts( array(
        'arg1' => '',
        'arg2' => ''
        ..... so on....

    ), $atts );

    extract($shortcode_data);

    // doing my programming with the shortcode

    // in the end echoing some html

    /*--------------------------------------*/

    // Now coming the script adding part

    $dir = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );

    /* CSS */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'some_style', $dir . 'assets/css/some_style.css', null, null );

    /* JS */
    wp_register_script ('some_script', $dir . 'assets/js/some_script.js');
    wp_localize_script( 'some_script', 'someData', $shortcode_data );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some_script', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some_other_script', $dir . 'assets/js/some_other_script.js');

});
```

Now my plugin is working perfectly well without any issue whatsoever but **now comes the big problem**. If I include this shortcode more than 1 time in one post or pages, it is going to push the same css and js files for every time the shortcode gets executed.

So, in the end, none of the shortcode will ever work properly as entire system is confused which data to pass to which js script.

If any of you can help me out on this weird problem it will be really helpful. I'm truly out of clues about how to fix this weird problem.

Comment: Are you sure the same script is getting double enqueued? Have you seen this? The WP enqueue system is meant to prevent this, so long as the name identifier and version are the same each time (which in your case they would be).

Comment: using oop you can solve this issue . Simply you have en queue the scripts in constructor of class .

Comment: Let me reverify. Give me 2 min

Comment: @HassanALi then how do I get the shortcode attribute values inside the constructor?

Comment: about that i m not sure because i dnt know the whole functioning of your plugin . But you have to restructure it according to oop .

Comment: @PatrickMoore You are right. they are not enqueuing more than once, but  2nd short is not performing at all and mostly showing the value of 1st shortcode

Comment: Perhaps you can echo some JavaScript in `<script></script>` instead of using `wp_localize_script()` ? See here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33008/how-to-add-a-javascript-snippet-to-the-footer-that-requires-jquery

Comment: @PatrickMoore yes I can do that but the js is too big and it is not a good way to do it. I'm taking a different approach with rand. I'll let you know if that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a different function to check for shortcode existence in a post and enqueued the required javascript and css for your slider.

e.g.

```
// Shortcode handler
add_shortcode('some_shortcode', function( $atts ) {

    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'arg1' => '',
        'arg2' => ''

    ), $atts );
    /** I would avoid using script localization unless you need script dependancy based on generated js from 
      * atts data. you can just return the js script directly on your content.
      * 
      */
    $script = '<script>(function {';
    $script .= "var arg1 = {$a['arg1']},";
    $script .= "    arg2 = {$a['arg2']}";
    $script .= '})(jQuery);</scipt>';
    return script;
});

// Script Dependancy Handling
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_style_handler');
function script_style_handler() {
    global $post;
    //check shortcode existence in post content and enque script/style if found
    if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'some_shortcode') && !is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'some_style', $dir . 'assets/css/some_style.css', null, null );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'some_other_script', $dir . 'assets/js/some_other_script.js');
    }
}
```